# jquery make action forr element append

Tags: jquery, append, chat, element, message

**I am doing a chat, I want to confirm each message send or not?**

I do not know how to define the class confirm append,
I want to make each class confirm to its answer

```
 $('#btn').click(function){
var message = $('textarea').val();

$('#chat').append(message+"&lt;span class="confirm">Sending...&lt;/span>");

$.post('chat.php', function(result){

if($.trim(result)==='ok'){

this class confirm html('sent');

}else{
this class confirm html('error');
}

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Correct your syntax errors
- Create a new element (like a DIV for example) by using `$("<div/>", {});` and store it into a variable
- After you get your PHP response use jQuery's `.addClass()` method to add the desired class to your *memorized* element

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {

  var message = $('textarea').val();

  // Create a new message element
  var $element = $("<div/>", {
    html: message + "<span class='confirm'>Sending...</span>",
    appendTo: "#chat"
  });

  // Check response and add class
  $.post('chat.php', {data: message}, function(result) {
    $element.addClass( $.trim(result) === 'ok' ? 'sent' : 'error')
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your syntax I believe you're looking for something like:

```
$('#btn').click(function){
var message = $('textarea').val();

$('#chat').append("<p>"+message+" <span class='confirm'>Sending...</span><p>");

$.post('chat.php', function(result){

if($.trim(result)==='ok'){

$(".confirm").text('sent');

}else{
$(".confirm").text('error');
}

}

}
```

but I don't think your POST is going to work. I assume you want to send the `message` to chat.php. For that you'll need something more like:

```
$.post( "chat.php", { message: message })
  .done(function( result ) {
    //
  });
```